# How to change the values of colorbar to cover all points?

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I am new to python and Julia. I want add a color bar to a scatter plot. But the values of colorbar just cover one group of points. How can I change the color bar to cover all the values? My code attached.

```
fig, ax = PyPlot.subplots()
n=100
x1 = rand(5:0.1:10, n)
x2 = rand(1:0.1:4, n)

y1 = rand(1:0.1:4, n)
y2 = rand(5:0.1:10, n)

cb1 = rand(6:0.1:10, n)
cb2 = rand(1:0.1:4, n)

sca = ax.scatter(x1, y1, marker="s", c=cb1, s=100)
ax.scatter(x2, y2, marker="o", c=cb2, s=100)

fig.colorbar(sca, ax=ax)

gcf()
```

[image]

I add this fig.colorbar(sca, ax=ax). But it didn't work.

Comment: You'd either add a second colorbar for the second group (preferably with different colors). Or you'd calculate a [norm](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormapnorms.html) that covers the full range of values.